# Scheme for Posts and Comments

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I need to allow Comments to different entities such as Posts, Products, etc:

1. One Post / Product / ... can have many comments;
2. One Comment can only be associated to a Post / Comment / ...

I though of different schemes and I came up with the following schemes and tables:

**1. Each entity has its own Comment table:**

```
    Posts (PostId), PostsComments (CommentId, PostId, CommentText)  
    Products (ProductId), ProductComents (CommentId, ProductId, CommentText)
```

It has the disadvantage of needing more tables if more entities need comments.

**2. One comment table for all entities (Many to Many):**

```
    Posts (PostId), PostsComments (CommentId, PostId)  
    Products (ProductId), ProductComents (CommentId, ProductId)  
    Comments (CommentId, CommentText)
```

It has the disadvantage of needing more tables if more entities need comments. Besides the Many to Many relationship ...

**3. One Forum table that aggregates comments:**

```
   Posts (PostId, ForumId)  
   Products (ProductId, ForumId)  
   Forums (ForumId)  
   Comments (CommentId, ForumId, CommentText)
```

In the future if I need another entity with comments I just add a ForumId FK to it.

What do you think about each approach? Do you have a better one?

Answer (score 0):

how about this one:

comments table will have info about post or product and may be both.

Comments (CommentId, PostId, ProductId, CommentText)

Comment: Later I will need to have Comments in other tables and not just Posts and Products ... So I would need to add more and more FKs to Comments table.